# How to find the declaredMethods in a java file or a text file containg code

Tags: java, parsing

i want to get the declaredMethods from input file containg java code.here is my code

```
public void parser()throws IOException{
   String Filecontent= readFile("print.txt");

   // returns the array of Method objects 
   Method[] m =Filecontent.getDeclaredMethods();
   for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("method = " + m[i].toString());
   }
}
```

But its not the correct way...kindly suggest the correct one...thanx

Comment: What about load the file in memory using ClassLoader and then use it?

Comment: You are going to need to compile the file (or at the very least parse it using a Context Free Grammar parser) in order to do so. javaCC offers this functionality, for example.

Comment: @amit i've to do parsing programatically instead of using any pasers....suggest something more helpful thnx

Comment: He said you can load in memory only .class files (not the extension, i mean byte code)